# Launch Dictation With Applescript

Tags: terminal, applescript, automator, voice-dictation

I would have thought this would be easy to find, but thus far it has not been for me.

Is there a way to launch dictation (fn, fn) with applescript or from the terminal?

Comment: You could try `SpeechRecognitionServer`, see https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3917259?start=0&tstart=0. I didn't get it to run, but you may have better luck... If you don't see `SpeechRecognitionServer` in the AppleScript Editor library this is the path: `/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechRecognition.framework/Versions/A/Resources/SpeechRecognitionServer.app`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just simulate pressing fn twice:

```
delay 0.3 -- time to release modifier keys if for example the script is run with command-R
tell application "System Events"
    key code 63
    key code 63
end tell
```

Or from a terminal:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to key code {63,63}'
```

The `osascript` command worked for me in Terminal but not in iTerm 2. The Start Dictation menu item also just plays the lower pitch sound without showing the popover in iTerm 2 though.

Comment: Any suggestions for this http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/101732/applescript-setting-select-drop-down